# Trying to create a website from scratch but past web app builds seem different

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I went to a new website in VS 2013 and selected web form application. But this does not seem the same as what i have been used to working on the past. On the left is the newly created web for app and on the right is the  site I've been working on, at my job. There are a controller folder, viewmodel, and views, and also no asp.net code like in the default.aspx page. I don't see any aspx pages in the web app in the right project. We coded in visual basic vb.net and how would I modify the new one to something I'm more comfortable with?
[image]

Comment: It looks like you have created an ASP.NET MVC Web Application. You should create a new project using the Visual Basic ASP.NET Web Forms Application template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created a different application type. The application on the right is an *MVC Project*. You've created a web forms project on the left.

You should figure out what your needs are and pick the best fit for them. If you just want to create something similar to work, create a new MVC Project by selecting it after choosing New Project from the menu.

Do a little reading on the differences in projects. MVC is a good one to create from scratch and learn, though.

Comment: oh ok. i really want to get pretty good. ill go the extra mile for it. ill read the differences. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have added Web Application project on left side and MVC project on right side.

If you want to create Web Form based application then you need to choose web application project template when adding project.

MVC Framework is different than Web Forms you need to learn it before using it, you can learn mvc from here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvc_framework/mvc_framework_introduction.htm